# Is it possible to access and modify a variable passed from Express in Pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm making a simple math game and wanted to pass an array of questions into Pug. If the user gets a question correct, I want to update the score and display a new question. However, I wasn't sure how I could access and update the website dynamically through Pug...

Passing the values in Express:

```
return res.render('play', { questions: questionArray, score: 0});
```

Pug file:

```
p#question #{questions[score].num1} #{questions[score].operation}  #{questions[score].num2} 
  p#score #{score}
  input#answer
  button.btn.btn-primary(onclick='checkAnswer(questions[score], score)') Enter
```

When I click the button to check the answer, I get the error "questions is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" in the console. I checked around on how to use onclick in Pug but it didn't seem to work. Some people suggested JSON.stringify, but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, [PUG String Interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html), like here;

```
p#question #{questions[score].num1} #{questions[score].operation}  #{questions[score].num2} 
    p#score #{score}
    input#answer
    button.btn.btn-primary#check-button Enter

script(type="text/javascript").
    document.getElementById('check-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        let score = !{score};
        let qScore = !{quesstions[score]}
        // put things in "checkAnswer" function here
    });
```

Hope this works! :)

Comment: Works great. Thank you so much!